# MATLAB - Labeling Curves During Iteration

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to show the p value that was used to generate each curve next to each of the curves plotted. Note that since there is a plot of E and -E, the same p value should be next to both. I've been attempting this for a while and I have not come across anything super useful.

```
t = -3.1;%coupling
a = 1;%distance between r1 and r3
n = 5;%latice vector span in a1 direction
m = 1;%latice vector span in a2 direction
i = -7;%unique axial vector t_hat direction
j = 11;%unique axial vector c_hat direction

max_p = abs((n*(i+j/2)-j*(m+n/2)));%# of unique p values
La = sqrt(3)*sqrt(m^2+n*m+n^2)*a/gcd(2*n+m,2*m+n);%unit cell length
C = sqrt(n^2+n*m+m^2);%circumference of the nanotube

hold on;
for p=0:1:max_p
    kt = -pi/La:.05:pi/La;
    kc = 2*pi*p/C;
    ka1 = kc*a*.5*(2*n+m)/C + kt*a*sqrt(3)*.5*m/C;
    ka2 = kc*a*.5*(n+2*m)/C - kt*a*sqrt(3)*.5*n/C;
    E = abs(t+t*exp(1i*ka2)+t*exp(1i*ka1));

    title_ = sprintf('(%d,%d) Carbon Nanotube Dispersion Diagram',n,m);
    title(title_);
    xlabel('k_{t}a');
    ylabel('Energy (eV)');
    plot(kt,E);
    plot(kt,-E);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a command named text that writes comments into the figures,

http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/text.html

with if you can't solve it with that and the to string operation i misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

First, do you need to plot both `E` and `-E`? Since these are the same except for their sign you don't really add any information to the plot by having `-E` there as well. However, if you do need both lines, then just construct an array of strings for the legend, during the loop, which has each string included twice (once for `E` and once for `-E`).

```
... Initial calculations ...

hold on;
for p=0:1:max_p
    kt = -pi/La:.05:pi/La;
    kc = 2*pi*p/C;
    ka1 = kc*a*.5*(2*n+m)/C + kt*a*sqrt(3)*.5*m/C;
    ka2 = kc*a*.5*(n+2*m)/C - kt*a*sqrt(3)*.5*n/C;
    E = abs(t+t*exp(1i*ka2)+t*exp(1i*ka1));

    plot(kt,E);
    plot(kt,-E);

    % Construct array containing legend text
    legend_text{2*(p+1)-1} = strcat('p=', num2str(p));
    legend_text{2*(p+1)}   = strcat('p=', num2str(p));

end

title_ = sprintf('(%d,%d) Carbon Nanotube Dispersion Diagram',n,m);
title(title_);
xlabel('k_{t}a');
ylabel('Energy (eV)');

legend(legend_text)
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way of constructing the legend text, but the above code works. Also, notice that I moved the calls to `xlabel`, `ylabel` and `title` to outside of the loop. This way they are only called once and not for each iteration of the loop.

Finally, you need to take care to ensure that each iteration of the loop plots with a different line colour or line style (see edit below). You could colour/style each pair of `E` and `-E` lines the same for a given iteration of the loop and just display the legend for `E` (or `-E`), which would obviously halve the number of legend entries. To do this you will need to hide one of line's handle visibility - this prevents it from getting an item in the legend. To do this use the following in your loop:

```
plot(kt, E);
plot(kt,-E, 'HandleVisibility', 'off');

% Construct array containing legend text
legend_text{p+1} = strcat('p=', num2str(p));
```

Finally, it is best to include `clear all` at the top of your Matlab scripts.

**Edit:** To have each plotted line use a different colour for each iteration of your loop use something like the following

```
... initial calculations ...

cmap = hsv(max_p);  % Create a max_p-by-3 set of colors from the HSV colormap

hold on;
for p = 0:1:max_p
  plot(kt,  E, 'Color', cmap(p,:));  % Plot each pair of lines with a different color
  plot(kt, -E, 'Color', cmap(p,:));
end
```